# Restore the deleted data when running the php artisan migrate:refresh

Tags: laravel-5

. How to retrieve the deleted data because i accidentally run the php artisan migrate:refresh without thinking ? is it possible to restore the data ?

Answer (score 0):

only if you have a database backup?

Comment: who is your db host? 3rd party hosts will have their own backups and will often be able to help retrieving the data